# yii2 captcha verification fails if you manually refresh the image

Tags: yii2, captcha

With the stock version of the yii2 captcha, if I click on the captcha image it will refresh the image ... for example if I can't read the first image.

But it doesn't seem to change the actual code, so that when I submit the form, the captcha variation fails.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Probably. Why are you expecting the code to change? it is just a link to an image and a variable in the session. The real question is: do you have ajax validation by any chance?

Comment: do you have pretty-url enabled?

Comment: The idea is that if you can't read the image, you can click the image and it will refresh. That's built in and works fine. But if you do refresh the image, the captcha test then fails. I need to double check on ajax validation. I have not enabled it. I did try disabling it, but that did not seem to make a difference, but I may have done it wrong. I do have pretty-url enabled.